# Frequent upvotes on low quality questions with [PowerBI] tag

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

I follow [powerbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi) tag and noticed that low quality (in my opinion) questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46558184/dax-measures-on-powerbi-import-mode-to-ssas-multidimensional) quite frequently (and consistently) receive upvotes (usually one).

I'm not sure where these originate from but suspect that one of possible sources could be sympathisers who suffer from lacking official documentation.

Is it acceptable to upvote low quality questions when they are reasonable and potentially useful? (For example, I think the linked question should be answered, not upvoted, not closed)

**EDIT:** Not sure how acceptable to ask, but please don't downvote the linked question. My question only used it as an example.

Comment: Are all those questions considered on-topic to you?

Comment: @E_net4 usually, yes.

Comment: I just asked because and off-topic question surge is something that could be taken action upon. Biased voting, on the other hand, is tolerated unless in case of fraud.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it acceptable to upvote low quality questions when they are reasonable and potentially useful?

Um, yes? Is that a trick question?

For one thing, quality is a pretty subjective metric. What you think is "low quality" might not be low quality to someone else. Clearly, the people who are voting up these questions don't think they're low quality.

Furthermore, the guidelines for upvoting are (quoted from the tooltip):

> This questions shows research effort; it is useful and clear

I think that makes pretty clear that it is acceptable to upvote questions that are "reasonable and potentially useful". If the official documentation for a product is non-existent or characteristically poor, then it makes sense that people would find questions about it useful. I might even go so far as to say that it is a *fact* that such questions are useful.

Speaking more broadly, it is also the case that different tags have different voting cultures. The quality and accessibility of the existing information on those technologies is certainly a contributing factor, as is the average experience/knowledge level of the developers who use those technologies. While this can be kind of confusing to people who use lots of different technologies and move between tags, it isn't necessarily a bad thing. Votes are, above all, a content rating system. If experts in those technologies find the questions to be interesting, useful, and relevant, then they should be upvoted.

If you see a question that looks like it is "reasonable and potentially useful" getting upvoted, but it is "low quality" in your eyes, then perhaps you should *edit* it to address the quality problems.

> For example, I think the linked question should be answered, not upvoted, not closed

Everyone is entitled to their own opinion. Voting here is a democratic process. If you don't think the question deserves an upvote, then don't upvote it.

The only time you should really become concerned about vote allocation is when you see a pattern of votes to *a particular user*. For example, if all of User X's questions get upvoted within minutes of being posted, especially when you consider them to be very low quality, then you might consider raising a moderator flag on one of User X's questions. Pick the "requires moderator intervention" option, and use the textbox provided to explain your concerns *in detail*. You don't need to link us to every question (we can find those easily), and trying to give all those links will quickly eat up the character limit. What is more useful to us are your observations: that you've seen a pattern, how quickly you've seen the votes come in, that you (as an expert) think the questions are not worth upvotes, etc. We'll use our tools to investigate whether there is vote fraud occurring.

Comment: This makes sense, many thanks. I guess what makes me unsure is "research effort".

Comment: But I can't just go around clarifying "Are you asking because you didn't search or because you didn't find an answer?"

Comment: Research effort is something each voter has to judge for themselves, @user5226582. The main reason it's in there is that the community has decided questions that can be trivially answered by looking at the documentation are not the types of questions we want to encourage here.

Comment: `Is that a trick question?` I'd say it is.  If you feel that the question is useful, and meets all of the site's guidelines, then *you're saying that the question isn't of low quality*.  If the question is of low quality then *it's not useful*.  Saying that a question is of low quality is a synonym for being not useful, so a question can't be both useful and of low quality, that's a paradox.

Comment: @user5226582 `But I can't just go around clarifying` not like that, no.  You simply won't get an honest answer.  People will always say they searched, even when they didn't.  As Cody mentioned, much of this comes down to you knowing how discoverable the information is, and having some idea of how likely the reader would have been to find the answer if they really did search.  If you do need to ask, there are other ways of phrasing a comment to avoid those problems, such as asking something like, "What did you find in your research on this topic and how did it fail to answer your question?"

Comment: @Servy I was thinking more along the lines of "helping askers learn the site" as if I were in the "First posts queue". Even though I understand where these questions are coming from (someone will ask this sooner or later), they show little research effort applied, usually have minor errors, which shouldn't be encouraged. But as Cody said, it's probably best to just try and edit.